# Is Bonjour supposed to make your home networking a lot easier?

Tags: network, bonjour

If Bonjour is installed on all PCs, Macs, is it supposed to make home networking a lot easier?  (the heaven of seeing all shared folders any where at home?)

(even the VLC Streamer on iPad claims to use Bonjour)

But now I go look for Bonjour, and Apple is saying it is a printer service:

http://support.apple.com/kb/dl999
Bonjour Print Services for Windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a word, yes. Printing is only part of it. http://www.apple.com/macosx/what-is-macosx/core-foundation.html gives a short description, and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonjour_(software) is a much more detailed one.

Answer (score 1):

That would be a particular Bonjour-using service (which will be bundled with Bonjour for Windows; BfW is also bundled with Safari, iTunes, and MobileMe for Windows, among others).  Apple doesn't distribute Bonjour for Windows (to end users; for developers/OEMs there's a package to be bundled with the OEM's own software) all by itself because most people want to *do* something with it, not just install it.  :)  (So you get what amounts to a naming artifact due to BfW technically being a separate package, just one that's always distributed along with something else.)